# How to deny service to IP based on the number connections per second or minute from that IP?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, multiple-instances, visitor-pattern

This is for DDoS Attack

Basically, I need to deny access to the site based on the specific number of connections in a specific time. Like 1 minute or 1 second. If an IP overlaps the maximum connections in an specific time, this IP will black listed with 1 day denegation.

For example: 1000 connections to the server in one minute is not normal, this ip will blacklisted.

What I want is an script to detect this in PHP. BUT!, very important: how to not deny service for Google-Bots or Search-bots and how to not deny for a normal visitor.

Comment: If your back-end server is running Linux, I highly recommend you do this in [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) instead of PHP.

Comment: DDOS attacks will usually target your server, not the page itself (PHP can't prevent it). they also use PROXY or hide their IP, wich make your solution not really optimal.

Comment: Agree with others here - if you *need* to protect yourself from DDos, then you need help from the larger infrastructure - if it's invoking your code, it's probably already winning.

Comment: psad is good. http://cipherdyne.org/psad/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this sort of thing should go into your app's code. This is something that you can implement at the network level. Your firewall may already provide this sort of thing. If you use IPTables in Linux, you can definitely implement rules of this sort.

One link that may help in the case of IPTables [is this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/).

[This link](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187) is actually better than above (thanks, Google!)

If you don't use Linux or your Firewall doesn't support this sort of feature, you can easily put a Linux box in front of your DB server and implement this method.